# Server REST, how pass an argument via @GET java

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jaxb, marshalling

i am stuck on this part of my project in which i must pass an argument via GET.

i have a bean called Measurement and a list of Measures.
I have to provide a method client side that can see the last N measurement. That is supposed to be a GET request with the parameter "N". Here is the slice of the code:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/info/measures")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) //dunno how to pass this
    public Response getMeasures(int numberOfMeasures) throws JAXBException, InterruptedException {
        String result = Ledger.getInstance().getMeasurementInformation(numberOfMeasures);
    
        if(result.equals(String.valueOf(errorStatus.BIGGER_SIZE)))
            return Response.status(400,"there aren't so much misures yet").build();
        else if(result.equals(String.valueOf(errorStatus.EMPTY_LIST)))
            return Response.status(400,"There are not measures yet").build();
        return Response.ok(result).build();
    }
```

getMeasuramentInformation:

```
    public String getMeasurementInformation(int numberOfMeasures) throws JAXBException, InterruptedException {
        ListOfMeasures aux = getInstance().getShallowMeasures();
        int size = aux.getSize();
        if(size == 0) return String.valueOf(errorStatus.EMPTY_LIST);
        else if(size < numberOfMeasures) {
            return String.valueOf(errorStatus.BIGGER_SIZE);
        }
        return Marshaller(ListOfMeasures.class,"listOfMeasures",
            new ListOfMeasures((aux.subList(size-numberOfMeasures,size))));
    }
```

How can i solve this problem? thanks for your kindness

Comment: `public Response getMeasures(@RequestParam("numberOfMeasures") int numberOfMeasures))` and consumer need to invoke like this "info/measures?numberOfMeasures=last N measurement value"

Comment: thanks! That solved my problem.